# App stopped responding on adding data to FireBase. Getting: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I'm new to FireStore, and when I was trying to insert a data using Hashmap it is showing error.

### This is the line which I'm adding to my firestore:

Map map = new HashMap<>();

```
    map.put("And","What");
    map.put("So","What Bro");

    firebaseFirestore.collection("mycollection").document("mydocument").set(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

---

And the error is:

---

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 13076
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125)
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.(GrpcUtil.java:203)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:84)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:48)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:73)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:113)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:256)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider$$Lambda$5.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.CharMatcher" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:125) 
        at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.(GrpcUtil.java:203) 
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:84) 
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:48) 
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27) 
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:73) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:113) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:256) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider$$Lambda$5.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzv.run(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:54) 
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                ... 17 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 16 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Comment: On which particular line of code are you getting the error?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I try adding this line: firebaseFirestore.collection("mycollection").document("mydocument").set(map)

Comment: I got the solution. After pasting this line of code in apps > Build.gradle file it worked fined.
-
Here is the code:
-

    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.1-android'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. After pasting this line of code in apps > Build.gradle file it worked fined.

Here is the code:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '28.1-android'
```